# CSS 'top' property has no effect

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting with CSS and would like to understand some behaviors.

I have this defined in a CSS file:

```
#spa {
position : absolute;
top      : 8px;
left     : 8px;
bottom   : 8px;
right    : 8px;

min-height : 500px;
min-width  : 500px;
overflow   : hidden;

background-color : #fff;
border-radius    : 0 8px 0 8px;
}

.spa-shell-head {
  top    : 0;
  left   : 0;
  right  : 0;
  height : 40px;
}
.spa-shell-head-logo {
  **top        : 4px;
  left       : 4px;**
  height     : 32px;
  width      : 128px;
  background : orange;
}

.spa-shell-head-acct {
  **top        : 4px;
  right      : 0;**
  width      : 64px;
  height     : 32px;
  background : green;
}
```

and this in my HTML file:

```
<body>
  <div id="spa">
    <div class="spa-shell-head">
      <div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>
      <div class="spa-shell-head-acct"></div>
      <div class="spa-shell-head-search"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="spa-shell-main">
      <div class="spa-shell-main-nav"></div>
      <div class="spa-shell-main-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="spa-shell-foot"></div>
    <div class="spa-shell-chat"></div>
    <div class="spa-shell-modal"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Why is it that I can change the bold properties to any number but the elements don't change? (at least the background colour that I have set to those elements)

Full code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/fu6dmhdt/1/

Comment: The elements with those classes are not positioned absolutely, so adding top and right won't change anything. I'm not sure what your comment about backgrounds means.

Comment: at least you need to add position absolute or relative or fixed so that top or bottom or left or right to effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because neither `.spa-shell-head-logo` nor `.spa-shell-head-acct` divs are positioned.

CSS `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` (offset) properties are only applicable to non-`static` `position`ed elements - i.e. elements have a `position` other than `static` (`fixed`, `absolute`, `relative`).

For instance, give them a position of `relative` to see the effect - **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/fu6dmhdt/2/)**.

Comment: oK, I was following a textbook. Not sure why they had those properties if they had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Top, Left, Bottom and Right property works depending upon the position. It absolutely work with when you assign position property to absolute/fixed.

Answer (score 0):

the properties of top, left, right, and bottom, will only work if you have declared the positions of the elements you are using the tags with as position absolute, or fixed. otherwise you will want to use margining.

as a side note, it will be very beneficial for you to try and keep all of your css in the same place. Once you start adding more css, it will likely become confusing!

hope this helps.