# Why image inline instead of random inside of div?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create left side of a matching game and I failed to randomly place the images. They always appear in a horizontal line instead of randomly in the div. Please advice, really appreciated!

edited: This isnt a duplicate question. As required, I cant link any outside CSS or JS file in making of this game.

edited: never mind, maybe it is a relative question to a previous one. Search didnt come up with that result thus the asking.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<header>
    <h1>Matching Gmae</h1>
    <p>Click on the extra smilling face on the left.</p>
</header>

<body onload="generateFaces()">
    <!--division styling -->
    <!--left-->
    <div id="leftSide" style="position:absolute; width:500px; height:500px"></div>
    <!--right-->
    <div id="rightSide" style="position:absolute; width:500px; height:500px; left:500px; border-left: 1px solid black;"></div>


    <!-- starting Javascript-->
    <script>
        var numberOfFaces = 5;
        var i = 0;
        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

        function generateFaces() {
            while (i < numberOfFaces) {
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
                img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px";
                img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px";
                theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    </script>>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS 'top' property has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065363/css-top-property-has-no-effect). `top` and `left` only apply to elements with a non-`static` `position`, e.g. `position:absolute;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Xufox wrote in the comment, a non-static `position` should be set for the `top` and `left` to have any effect.

The "duplicate" question does not explain how to do that in JavaScript, though.

In your script, that means you should add:

```
img.style.position = 'absolute';
```